# How to bind these events to the same text?(Python tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to bind these two events to the same text and make a link, but I found that `<Button-1>` and `<ButtonPress-1>`, `<ButtonRelease-1>` cannot exist at the same time, `<ButtonPress-1>`, `<ButtonRelease-1>` will make `<Button-1>` not working, this is my source code.

```
def link(textobj, place, color, underline, execcmd, var):
exec('textobj.tag_add(var, place[0], place[1])')
exec('textobj.tag_config(var, foreground = color[0], background = color[1], underline = underline)')
textobj.config(cursor = 'arrow')
def show_hand_cursor(event):
    textobj.config(cursor = 'hand2')

def show_xterm_cursor(event):
    textobj.config(cursor = 'xterm')

def onclick(event):
    nonlocal execcmd
    exec(execcmd)

def onmousedown(event):
    nonlocal textobj, var, color
    exec('textobj.tag_config(var, foreground = color[3], background = color[1])')

def onmouseup(event):
    nonlocal textobj, var, color
    exec('textobj.tag_config(var, foreground = color[2], background = color[1])')

exec("textobj.tag_bind(var, '<Enter>', show_hand_cursor)")
exec("textobj.tag_bind(var, '<Leave>', show_xterm_cursor)")
exec("textobj.tag_bind(var, '<Button-1>', onclick)")
exec("textobj.tag_bind(var, '<ButtonPress-1>', onmousedown)")
exec("textobj.tag_bind(var, '<ButtonRelease-1>', onmouseup)")
```

what should I do?

Comment: Why are you using `exec()`.

Comment: This is a function, what else can be used without exec()?

Comment: Why? Just remove `exec()`.

Comment: I would say that `exec()` is used very rarely and not suggested anyways

Comment: var passes in a string, but this function needs to turn it into a variable name to store

Comment: `<Button-1>` is the same as `<ButtonPress-1>`, so the binding on `<ButtonPress-1>` will override the one on `<Button-1>`.

Comment: This works, but it slows down